# Angular RX/JS Nested Observable calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have problems wrapping my head around how to achieve the following Problem with Reactive programming:

I want to call a Method `getSearchResults(searchterm: string): Observable<Foo[]>`. In this method I normally filter data from a locally stored `dataset`. Only if this dataset is not loaded, I want to load my `dataset` from the server first:

```
getSearchResults(searchterm: string): Observable<Foo[]> {
  if(this.dataset != null) {
    return this.filter(this.dataset, searchterm);
  }

  // Load dataset first from server. service method returns an Observable
  const obs = myService.loadDataset();
  obs.subscribe(data => {
     this.dataset = data;

     // Now I want to call filter and return an Observable
     return this.filter(this.dataset, searchterm);
  });

}
```

Consider this as pseudocode and no full example, but I hope it makes my problem clear. I understand, that this does not work in this manner.

But I really have a hard time to find a pattern to achieve something like this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include rxjs observable `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

And then create your own observable.

```
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const obs = myService.loadDataset();
      obs.subscribe(data => {
         this.dataset = data;

         // Now I want to call filter and return an Observable
         observer.next(this.filter(this.dataset, searchterm));
      });
   });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for five hours now! Thank you very much!

Comment: it triggers myService.loadDataset() on each subscription for result observable, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it does, but for that i check with an `if` if data is already loaded...
Meaning: I only create this Observable if the data hasn't been loaded already...)

Comment: hm, okay. other issue there - you loose complete/error which can be emitted by data set observable. as you delegate only observer.next invocation in subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert observable to promise, like this:

```
async getSearchResults(searchterm: string): Promise<Foo[]> {
    if(this.dataset != null) {
        return await this.filter(this.dataset, searchterm). toPromise();
    }

    // Load dataset first from server. service method returns an Observable
    const data = await myService.loadDataset().toPromise();
 // Now I want to call filter and return an Observable
   return await this.filter(this.dataset, searchterm). toPromise ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following logic is simple and straightforward to achieve the goal:

```
localDataLoaded = false;

yourLocalDataAsObservable.pipe(
filter()
).subscribe(
data => {this.localDataLoaded = true;},
error => {},
() => {if (!localDataLoaded) {
// Load data from server, because the data you need is not in the local store
}}
```

)